# VBA code to extract multiple words within multiple bracket from a text file

Tags: excel, vba

How to take input from a text file and extract each word within the square bracket (a simple text within each bracket) to an Excel sheet.

For example:

text file->(Hi this is [john doe] and phone number is [12345]..... )
output->john doe
        12345

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If all of the strings are the same, it would be easiest to open the notepad document, go to edit, replace and replace all brackets with commas and just before the content write what the headers would be. for example, your file would look like:

remove, name, remove, phone
Hi this is ,john doe, and phone number is ,12345,

then save it as file.csv, open the file in excel, and remove the columns that say remove on them

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim fileNr As Integer
    Dim lines() As String
    Dim iLine As Long
    Dim arr As Variant

    fileNr = FreeFile '<--| get a free file index for subsequent `Open` statement
    Open "C:\Users\Luvish\Data\Test.txt" For Input As #fileNr '<--| open your file (change path and name as per your actual needs
        lines = Split(Input$(LOF(fileNr), fileNr), vbNewLine) '<-- read all lines
    Close fileNr '<--| close text file

    For iLine = 0 To UBound(lines) '<--| loop through all read lines
        If InStr(lines(iLine), "]") > 0 Then '<--| if current line has a "]" character
            arr = Split(Replace(lines(iLine), "]", "]["), "[") '<--| split current line and collect wanted data in even index elements
            MsgBox Left(arr(1), Len(arr(1)) - 1) & " " & Left(arr(3), Len(arr(3)) - 1) '<--| build your current line data
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @Luvish, did you get through it?